# Jquery SparkLine does not render properly in IE8

Tags: jquery

I am displaying inline charts using SparkLine. When I click on the inline chart which is dislayed in a cell in a table, I get an error in jquery.min.js. However it does not show any error. I get a message failed. Is there a good way to find what the error is. I say break and here is where it breaks:

```
function(a){var b=a.target,c=b.type;(c==="submit"||c==="image")&&f(b).closest("form").length&&L("submit",this,arguments)})
```

It breaks at c=b.type.

How do I know the source of this error. Mind you it works well in FireFox.

Answer (score 0):

change `,` to `;` for IE to work

So we get:

```
function(a){var b=a.target;var c=b.type;(c==="submit"||c==="image")&&f(b).closest("form").length&&L("submit",this,arguments)})
```

Comment: Assuming it's commas-separated variable declarations that are broken, should also put 'var' after the semicolon and before the c.

Comment: I get the same error at this line: else if (c !== "input" || a.type !== "checkbox" && a.type !== "radio")

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common for a plug-in to be the source of an "error in jQuery", because it is after all accessing jQuery methods. In the tangle, the browser sees that it's jQuery breaking even though it may well be the way the plug-in is calling the jQuery function.

I would be surprised if things were THAT broken in minimized jQuery for IE8. That many bugs would have long since been discovered and fixed. Rather, there's something else that we're missing.

I would be curious to know if jQuery is accidentally included twice, in what order, and through which methods. As PeeHaa suggests, a demo would be handy.